# Correct way to use include and includeonly when writing a large document like a thesis

Tags: include

I am writing a large document with several chapters and I would like to work on each chapter separately. In my `main.tex` I include the chapters either like

```
 \include{chap1.tex}
 \include{chap2.tex}
 \include{chap3.tex}
```

or

```
 \input{chap1.tex}
 \input{chap2.tex}
 \input{chap3.tex}
```

I think `\include` is preferable if I want things to be referenced and cited correctly? but doing it the `\include` way `latex main.tex` I don't get any `dvi` output whereas with `\input` things compile fine to `dvi`. What's going wrong here?

I would then like to use `\includeonly` (or `\excludeonly` ) to work on individual sections of the document whilst maintaining the referencing etc.

A `mwe` can be handy:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\includeonly{chap1}

\begin{document}
  \include{chap1}
  \include{chap2}
  \include{chap3}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't know if this is related to your problem, but I think you could remove the file extensions. Otherwise, perhaps a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) would help.

Comment: I believe you should use `\include` at the level of a control file calling files for your chapters.  On a related note, I found that `\include` is problematic inside a `\chapter`.  So `\input` is also handy.

Comment: @fpghost You might want to look at [When should I use \input vs. \include?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246), which looks quite similar to this question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When should I use \input vs. \include?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Cross referencing and citation should work fine with `\input`. `input` is more or less invisible to the TeX processing, it just allows you to split up the file into smaller units for ease of editing.

If you do not use `\includeonly` then `\include{file}` is more or less the same as `\clearpage\input{file}\clearpage` so like `\input` but with forced page breaks. Since your chapter head probably forces a page break anyway this means that switching between `\input` and `\include` should not affect output.

If you use `\include` then you can use `\includeonly` to speed up processing by just typesetting specified chapters. Note however that it will use old `aux` files for the other chapters to get the numbering more or less correct. Thus you should occasionally (and initially) process the file without `\includeonly` so that all chapters are processed and usable `aux` files are generated for each chapter.

---

As noted by @Corentin in the comment, in the case of `\include` it is important that you use the file name *without* `.tex` at the end: `\include{file1}` not `\include{file1.tex}`.

Comment: Is it worth noting that `\include` is mainly for chapters?

Comment: @JosephWright Well if your style also has sections within chapters starting a new page, it's fine to use include for sections as well. It is the page break rather than the sectioning depth that is important.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle could you add a `mwe` using `\includeonly`?

Comment: @nilon not sure what you'd want, it is the questioner's responsibility to provide the mwe really. given the list of `\include` in the question the mwe would just have `\includeonly{chap1}` in the preamble to just process the first chapter.