# Compile pages x-y in LaTex

Tags: compiling

I was wondering if given a huge Latex `\documentclass[oneside]{book}` is it possible to compile a specific range of pages, for example pages 11-35, to a PDF?

I want to compile a single chapter without having to copy and paste content, and move relevant packages into the new file.

I use Kile as my IDE.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't compile a range of pages as in your example 11-35, because LaTeX must first set the pages 1 to 10 in order to know what page 11 is. You can compile single parts of your document using `\include` and `\includeonly`.

Comment: Thanks, that might actually be enough for my needs. Cheers.

Comment: Look e.g. at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87010 and references therein.

Comment: I think you want to look at the `pagesel` package.

Comment: @egreg: ok, now I'm quite baffled... never heard of that. Ashes on my head.

Comment: @egreg: on second thoughts, I might have simply misinterpreted the question. As far as I understand, `pagesel` _does_ compile the entire document but ships out only the requested pages. However, the typesetting must be performed anyway. Since the OP asked about "compiling a specific range of pages", I immediately thought about `\include`.

Comment: If you use WinEdt, it a has toolbar button `Compile selected` that launches a macro which creates a temporary file with the preamble of your file and only the selection as the body of the document.

Comment: @Bernard I'm using Ubuntu. Don't think it's available for that.

Comment: I've seen it works under Wine. If it's only for a few documents, you may give it a try for free for 1 month.

Comment: @Docconcoct exactly which LaTeX are you using on Ubuntu? If you are using the version from the Ubuntu repositories, there are lots of those you may need to figure out exactly which Ubuntu package provides that package. I use the Vanilla TeX Live 2015, manually installed, this include `pagesel`

Comment: @Bernard isn't it a plain LaTeX package, how is Wine related to this?

Comment: @daleif: No, I mentioned the WinEdt macro `compileselected.edt`.  WinEdt is just a dedicated editor for Windows. But I read once it works fine under Wine.

Comment: @Bernard ok, that makes more sense.