# Ghost environment

Tags: environments, comments

I am trying to do the following. I would like a part of my source to be compiled normally but to generate no output. In particlular, I would like references made to the ghosted parts to be produced the same results as if the parts were not ghosted.

I know this sounds bizarre and I have not seen anything doing something like that.

I would have no trouble with a solution that does not process floats in the ghosted parts.

Here is an idea of the code I would like:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{ghost} % package that would define the ghost environement
\begin{document}
\section{First}
Some text here with a reference \ref{eq:one} and 
another reference \ref{se:third}
%\begin{ghost}
\section{Second}
Some text again.
\begin{equation}\label{eq:one}
a = b
\end{equation}
%\end{ghost}
\section{Third}\label{se:third}
Some final text
\end{document}
```

that would produce the following output (once the ghost environment works):

[image]

Comment: I haven't tried, but `\includeonly` may solve your problem if you're willing to have the ghost environments in separate files. (You might avoid that with `\filecontents`.)  See the accepted answer to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87010/correct-way-to-use-include-and-includeonly-when-writing-a-large-document-like-a

Comment: I think the idea here is `conditional compilation`. One define new test `\ifghost`, the environment `ghost` is defined to do nothing by default and save its contents into `\vbox` (see Steven B. Segletes' answer below) if the condition `\ghosttrue`. `\ifghost` is set to true only in final compilation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

EDITED to actually work (I think).

My approach is to create a `ghost` environment whereby I stick the ghost material into a box that isn't printed.  I first tried it into an `lrbox`, but that choked on `\label`s.  So I had some success using the *bad* syntax of `\setbox0=\vbox\bgroup...\egroup`.  I figured that since I wasn't typesetting the material anyway, the *bad* aspects to the formulation may not be fatal.

This worked well at actuating the sectioning information without actually printing it, so I was halfway to solving the problem.  However, executing `\label` in a box also broke things.

So my solution was to grab the meaning of `\label` and rather than executing the code in the box, I would just `\xdef` the code to an indexed macro (`\LBLi`, `\LBLii`, `\LBLiii`) for each invocation of `\label`.  Then, upon exiting the box, I would cycle through a loop executing `\LBLi`, `\LBLii`, `\LBLiii`, successively, to actually execute the `\label` code outside of the box.

With a little effort, I got it to work.  What `\label` is supposed to do is write the following *evaluated* line to the aux file:

```
\newlabel{<label>}{{\@currentlabel}{\thepage}}
```

so that the actual aux file contains something like `\newlabel{eq:one}{{1}{1}}`.

My EDIT involved using an `\xdef` instead of a `\gdef` in the definitions of `\LBLx`, with `\noexpand` preserved on `\thepage`.  The `\xdef` allowed the proper value of `\@currentlabel` to be employed.

Here is my MWE, which works for the label numbers.  It seems to work for the `\thepage`, as well, which can be tested in my MWE, by uncommenting the `\vspace*` line.

RE-EDITED to incorporate `\newif\ifghost`, per touhami's comment to the question.  Setting `\ghostfalse` near the top of the preamble will cause the compilation to ignore `ghost` and compile the full document.  With `\ghosttrue`, the `ghost`  sections are omitted, but hopefully accounted for.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newif\ifghost
\ghosttrue
\newcounter{nlabels}
\newcounter{ilabel}
\ifghost
  \makeatletter
  \def\pwr{\protected@write\@auxout}
  \newenvironment{ghost}{\setcounter{nlabels}{0}%
    \renewcommand\label[1]{\stepcounter{nlabels}%
    \expandafter\xdef\csname LBL\romannumeral\value{nlabels}\endcsname{%
    {}{\string\newlabel{##1}{{\@currentlabel}{\noexpand\thepage}}}}}%
    \par\setbox0=\vbox\bgroup}{\egroup%
      \setcounter{ilabel}{0}%
      \whiledo{\value{ilabel}<\value{nlabels}}{%
       \stepcounter{ilabel}%
       \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\pwr%
         \csname LBL\romannumeral\value{ilabel}\endcsname%
      }%
  }
  \makeatother
\else
  \newenvironment{ghost}{}{}
\fi
\begin{document}
%\vspace*{6in}% Seems to work if I split the page during ghost.
\section{First}\label{se:first}
Reference to equations \ref{eq:one}, \ref{eq:two}, \ref{eq:three} 
and \ref{eq:four}, and 
another reference to sections \ref{se:first}, \ref{se:second} and \ref{se:third}.
\begin{equation}\label{eq:one}
y = mx+b
\end{equation}
\begin{ghost}
\section{Second}\label{se:second}
Some text again.
\begin{equation}\label{eq:two}
a = b
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:three}
c = d
\end{equation}
\end{ghost}
\section{Third}\label{se:third}
Some final text to see if next equation number is correct
\begin{equation}\label{eq:four}
e = mc^2
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For this MWE, the aux file is written as

```
\relax
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1}First}{1}}
\newlabel{se:first}{{1}{1}}
\newlabel{eq:one}{{1}{1}}
\newlabel{se:second}{{2}{1}}
\newlabel{eq:two}{{2}{1}}
\newlabel{eq:three}{{3}{1}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {3}Third}{1}}
\newlabel{se:third}{{3}{1}}
\newlabel{eq:four}{{4}{1}}
```

Comment: what about `\pageref`?

Comment: @touhami I'm not sure your exact question.  I seem to be able to include `\pageref` calls either inside or outside of the `ghost` environment, so help me to understand your concern.

Comment: Here the contents of `ghost` environment is short, suppose that this contents is long (example `\lipsum[1-30]` after `eq:one`) in this case `\pageref{eq:one}` and `\pageref{eq:three}` shouldn't refer the same page.

Comment: it seems to be extension of `http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pagesel` package

Comment: @touhami The `ghost` environment will never be able to (nor should it) keep track of theoretical page number that *would* occur if the environment were turned off.  Rather, it can only be expected to provide the page number of the actual page into which it would be inserted.

Comment: @touhami thus, to the point, in your `\lipsum[1-30]` hypothetical example, I would contend that both equations should indeed provide the page number "1", as that is the page into which the removed lengthy `ghost` environment would be inserted.

Comment: please see my comment to the question.

Comment: @touhami I have incorporated a `\newif`, based on your comments.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to sum up the differences between Steven's solution and using `\include`/`\includeonly` (as suggested by Ethan Bolker) in a separate answer.  I didn't really do a thorough comparison with Steven's solution, so if you find anything else, feel free to add to this post.

1. With `\include`, the ghost part has to be stored in a separate file.  As Ethan writes, this can be circumvented using `\filecontents`.
2. Whenever a file is included, a new page is started.  Also, at the end of the included file, a new page is started.  This may not always be the desired behaviour, but it also has advantages: The text surrounding the `\include` will always be typeset in the same manner, no matter whether the file is actually included or not.  Also the page counter is adjusted to respect the 'hidden' pages.  Therefore, the hidden text is distributed over invisible pages, and it is possible to refer to these hidden pages, as touhami desires in his comment.