# amsmath messes with label hack

Tags: amsmath, labels, latex3

I am adapting to LaTeX3 the code given [there](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/271762/) to provide for an environment the content of which is not displayed but the labels of which are taken into account.

The idea is to typeset the content into a vbox to be discarded, but before that, to change the meaning of `\label` to a new `\qlabel` command that stores label information into a clist, and thereafter to process the clist with `\dolabels` to output relevant label information into `.aux`.

This seems to work… until `amsmath` is loaded, whether before or after the code. What happens is the reference to the non-typeset labels are undefined. I have reason to believe that `amsmath` somehow makes it difficult to change the meaning of `\label` (the clist remains empty), but I am at a complete loss as to how to eschew this.

Here is my code. Compiling (with LuaLaTeX) as is correctly gives references (2) (1) (4) at the end. Uncommenting one of the `\usepackage{amsmath}` gives (??) (1) (4) instead.

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{amsmath}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter

\clist_new:N \g__chato_exo_labels_cl
\box_new:N \l__chato_exo_dummy_box

\cs_new:Nn\cs__chato_exo_dolabels:nnn{\@bsphack \protected@write \@auxout {}{\string \newlabel {#1}{{#2}{#3}}}\@esphack}
\cs_new:Nn\cs__chato_exo_qlabel:n{\clist_gput_right:Nx \g__chato_exo_labels_cl { {{#1}{\@currentlabel}{\thepage}} } }


\NewDocumentEnvironment{question}{O{}}
{\begingroup\let\ltx@label\cs__chato_exo_qlabel:n\vbox_set:Nw \l__chato_exo_dummy_box}
{\vbox_set_end:\endgroup\clist_map_inline:Nn \g__chato_exo_labels_cl {\cs__chato_exo_dolabels:nnn ##1}}

\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff

%\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
i,i,i, \label{eq2}
\end{equation}

\begin{question}[truc]
choucroute
\begin{equation}
i,i,i, \label{eq1}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
oon \label{eq}
\end{equation}
\end{question}

\begin{equation}
i,i,i, \label{eq3}
\end{equation}

(\ref{eq1}) (\ref{eq2}) (\ref{eq3})
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't get a correct result with your code, `\ltx@label` is not defined and so never executed. With amsmath the code work ok but will probably break if you load hyperref.

Comment: Oh, maybe I need to use ``\label`` when ``amsmath`` is not loaded and ``\ltx@label`` when it is ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Ulrike Fischer for pointing out the `\ltx@label` thing. It is the original `\label` when `amsmath` is loaded -- I had been fumbling so much with all of this that I had lost track of that.

Thanks for indicating a problem with `hyperref`. I got it to compile by taking the meaning it gives to `\label` and storing the relevant information. I did not check whether the links actually work -- I of course do not expect links to non-typeset parts to.

EDIT : `amsmath` messes with `\label` not globally (upon package loading), but locally when a math environment is started. So if we only change the meaning of `\ltx@label`, we get equations to work, but not captions of figures (because they use the original `\label`).

So we need to change both :

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter

\clist_new:N \g__chato_exo_labels_cl
\box_new:N \l__chato_exo_dummy_box


\@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}
  {
    \cs_new:Npn\cs__chato_exo_dolabels#1#2#3#4#5{\@bsphack \begingroup \def \label@name {#1}\label@hook \protected@write \@auxout {}{\string \newlabel {#1}{{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{}}}\endgroup \@esphack}
    \cs_new:Nn\cs__chato_exo_qlabel:n{\clist_gput_right:Nx \g__chato_exo_labels_cl { {{#1}{\@currentlabel}{\thepage}{\@currentlabelname}{\@currentHref}} } }
  }
  {
    \cs_new:Npn\cs__chato_exo_dolabels#1#2#3{\@bsphack \protected@write \@auxout {}{\string \newlabel {#1}{{#2}{#3}}}\@esphack}
    \cs_new:Nn\cs__chato_exo_qlabel:n{\clist_gput_right:Nx \g__chato_exo_labels_cl { {{#1}{\@currentlabel}{\thepage}} } }
  }

\NewDocumentEnvironment{question}{O{}}
{\group_begin:\cs_set_eq:NN\label\cs__chato_exo_qlabel:n
\@ifpackageloaded{amsmath}{\cs_set_eq:NN\ltx@label\cs__chato_exo_qlabel:n}{}\vbox_set:Nw \l__chato_exo_dummy_box}
{\vbox_set_end:\group_end:\clist_map_inline:Nn \g__chato_exo_labels_cl {\cs__chato_exo_dolabels ##1}}

\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff
```