# Hide some text without hiding it from the table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning

I know what I am trying to do could sound contrived. However, I am just writing my thesis. I am the beginning of the work, so I started writing down my table of contents, so as to provide a scaffolding for my work.

Now, while I would like to have my table of contents fully displayed, there are tons of titles and subtitles under it without any content, and that's irritating indeed.

Can I make that huge bunch of titles and subtitles disappear, without deleting those from the table of contents? I tried wrapping them inside an `\iffalse` - `\fi` couple, but while indeed they were no longer displayed, they also disappeared from my table of contents.

What should I do? I don't care if the trick is dirty, it's just to have everything more tidy while I am still developing my contents.

Comment: If I understand this is the job of `\includeonly` command see for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87010/correct-way-to-use-include-and-includeonly-when-writing-a-large-document-like-a

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I propose a `\TODO` prefix to the command for a chapter/section/subsection that has no contents yet:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{xparse}% for easier management of optional arguments

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\TODO}{msom}
 {
  \IfBooleanF{#1}% do nothing if it's starred
   {
    \cs_if_eq:NNT #1 \chapter { \cleardoublepage\mbox{} }
    \refstepcounter{\cs_to_str:N #1}
    \IfNoValueTF{#3}
     {
      \addcontentsline{toc}{\cs_to_str:N #1}{\protect\numberline{\use:c{the\cs_to_str:N #1}}#4}
     }
     {
      \addcontentsline{toc}{\cs_to_str:N #1}{\protect\numberline{\use:c{the\cs_to_str:N #1}}#3}
     }
   }
  \cs_if_eq:NNF #1 \chapter { \mbox{} }% allow page breaks after sections
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction}

This has contents, which will be completed according
to the results in section~\ref{sec:procr}.

\chapter{Main thing}

\section{Whatever}

This has contents.

\TODO\section{Procrastination}\label{sec:procr}

\TODO\section[Short title for this one]
  {This section has a very very long title}

\TODO\chapter{Developments}

\end{document}
```

When you start writing contents, just remove the `\TODO` prefix.

[image]

Comment: Very interesting approach...I'm learning something new today! I noticed that the third chapter (Developments) won't appear in the TOC unless there is some text after it. Could you explain why that is?

Comment: @Guho Because I forgot to force some text in the page. ;-) Thanks for noting.

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing the specifics of your setup makes it difficult to answer conclusively. A (relatively) generic approach that wouldn't require diving into each sectioning command would be to first establish a switch, indicating if the heading should be shown (set to true below):

```
\newif\ifshowheadings \showheadingstrue
```

With that, a "wrapper" command could be defined to evaluate each of the headings, showing it if `\showheadingstrue` and not if `\showheadingsfalse`:

```
\def\showheadings#1{\ifshowheadings#1\else\relax\fi}
```

Each of the sections would then be placed as the argument to this command, for example:

```
\showheadings{\chapter{Test}}
\showheadings{\section{Subsection Test}}
```

When the document is run with `\showheadingstrue`, all of the headings will be included in the TOC, with the appropriate `\contentsline` commands written to the `toc` file. Depending on the class, the `\tableofcontents` command could be replicated with:

```
\chapter*{Contents}
\input{\jobname.toc}
```

Therefore, to divorce the *actual* TOC from the *displayed* TOC, you could change `\jobname` to an alternative name (e.g., `schematictoc`). Wrapping this change into a command might look like:

```
\def\switchedtableofcontents{\ifshowheadings\tableofcontents\else\chapter*{Contents}\input{schematictoc.toc}\fi}
```

Accordingly, an approach would be to layout your thesis as you have detailed with `\showheadingstrue`. Process your document, resulting in the `toc` file corresponding to the layout. Then, change the name of the `toc` file to `schematictoc.toc` and set `\showheadingsfalse`. Thereafter, any changes to the document would not be reflected in the displayed TOC.

Put together:

```
\documentclass{report}
\newif\ifshowheadings \showheadingstrue
\def\showheadings#1{\ifshowheadings#1\else\relax\fi}
\def\switchedtableofcontents{\ifshowheadings\tableofcontents\else\chapter*{Contents}\input{schematictoc.toc}\fi}
\begin{document}


\switchedtableofcontents

\showheadings{\chapter{Test}}
\showheadings{\section{Subsection Test}}
\showheadings{\chapter{Test}}
\showheadings{\section{Subsection Test}}
\showheadings{\chapter{Test}}
\showheadings{\section{Subsection Test}}
\showheadings{\chapter{Test}}
\showheadings{\section{Subsection Test}}
\end{document}
```