# processing part of a document with no output

Tags: cross-referencing

The document is split into files

```
\input{f1}
\input{f2}
\input{f3}
```

I would like to have f2 processed into .aux so that f1 and f3 can refer to f2 equation labels, but with no pages of f2 included in the output. 
I could set other counters (page etc.) by hand in f3 to obtain continuous numeration in f1+f3.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! This is what `\include` accomplishes. Using `\includeonly` you could only include some part of the document while keeping the counters "intact".

Comment: Although @marmot is correct, it might be useful to clarify that you need to include all files at least once to generate the labels (see, e.g., https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87011/)

Comment: Thank you - \include only does the trick indeed.