# Is there a way to create LaTex "object files" like in c in order to write a proper Makefile

Tags: makefile

I am trying to write a Makefile for a LaTeX project which uses more than one .tex file. I was wondering, if it is possible to create several pdf's (or any other data format) for each .tex and link them in the end together to the main pdf in order to save time within the compilation process.

Excerpt from the current Makefile:

```
build/target.pdf: ./content/target.tex
    latexmk ./content/target.tex
```

In the content file there are several .tex files.
Now I would like to do something similar to c-style Makefiles e.g:

```
BUILD_DIR = build
$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: %.tex
    latexmk ./content/%.tex
```

and then link again all the object files together

Comment: I do not understand the problem: if `target.tex` includes files, `latexmk` will automatically rebuild it as soon as any dependence (even the system files!) changes. If you are seeking separate compilations to speed up the build, that is generally not possible (there are exceptions, like the externalize library for Ti*k*Z)

Comment: concatenating pdf is quite hard (although there are tools that can do that) however in most documents the chapters are not independent so separate compilation is not possible anyway, page numbers or any cross references between chapters mean that a change in one chapter can change the typesetting of all the others

Comment: If you want to speed up the compilation while you are working on the document, i.e., a full output of all chapters is not required during editing, then you can use conditional compilation, see for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87010/correct-way-to-use-include-and-includeonly-when-writing-a-large-document-like-a.