# Is there a way to write my Thesis in separate files for each chapter and then merge them into one main.tex at the end?

Tags: thesis

I am starting to write my materials and methods section of my thesis. My Supervisor would rather have one chapter at a time to an extent so I was wondering if it is possible to have separate documents for each chapter with identical preamble and bibtex files attached and then just link them all up in a single latex document.

In the main latex document I would then want to auto generate the ToC in the correct format, have references work across chapters and be able to have my title page etc in main.

Is this possible or should I just write it all as one document?

Comment: Look at `\include` and `\includeonly`.  That has been asked like a thousand times.  I'll try to find the duplicate.

Comment: Another one: [Correct way to use include and includeonly when writing a large document like a thesis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87010/correct-way-to-use-include-and-includeonly-when-writing-a-large-document-like-a)