# How to include only some sections in a book

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning

I am writing a long recipe book, with many hundreds of recipes (just my family recipes, gathered through over a century).  Every recipe is a section.  I would like to flag out some of the recipes as "important", so that I can print a reduced version of the book if I need. 
That is, I would like to mark some sections some way, like:

```
\section[imp]{My recipe}
```

and others simply like

```
\section{A non-important recipe}
```

Then, in the main, I could have an option `\importantonly` or `\allrecipes` that causes either only the important ones, or all of them, to be included.

Is there a package that does this already?  It would be easy to do if a section was a `\begin{section}`...`\end{section}`; the challenge in doing it as I see it is that sections have a beginning, but their end is not clearly marked.  So I would not know offhand how to write a macro for the conditional output.

As I have hundreds of recipes already, I would prefer a way where I need to make only small modifications in place; I cannot make every section its own file.

Comment: One idea is to divide your book chapters into separate files and print them in the main file by include file command. Then when you need the compact version just select the include only files of the important chapters that you want.

Comment: Here you may find how to use include and include only https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87010/correct-way-to-use-include-and-includeonly-when-writing-a-large-document-like-a

Comment: I might approach this by defining a new environment that would serve to delimit the beginning and end of a recipe, much like your `\begin{section} ... \end{section}` but not requiring redefinition of anything existing.  Defining a new `\ifimportant` would permit the placement of `\importanttrue` before only the important recipes, and on entering a recipe, checking `\ifimportant`.  If true, reset `\global\importantfalse` and process the recipe, otherwise skip over it.  (Not tested; at the moment, I don't have a working TeX system available.)

Comment: You could pass a number to your environment and compare it to a threshold counter (sort of like secnumdepth).  BTW, naming an environment `section` would conflict with the `\section` macro.