# TeXstudio - Compile a single section to pdf

Tags: sectioning, compiling, texstudio

I want to create a pdf with a single section out of all of my sections.
How can I make TeXstudio output a specific section as pdf?

Comment: Use one file per section and input / include them into a main file, see e.g. [Correct way to use include and includeonly when writing a large document like a thesis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/87010/123129).

Comment: The [subfiles package](https://ctan.org/pkg/subfiles?lang=en) might be another option, though I'd probably just use `\include` myself.