# Cross links not updating properly using Overleaf

Tags: overleaf, cross-link

I'm having a project which having Ten chapters and the project is in `Overleaf`. Each chapter having two `TeX` application files, e.g., `ch01.tex` having the actual content for `Chapter 1` and `Ch01run.tex` having the preamble tags like `\documentclass...`  etc.), sample `MWE` is:

**Ch01.tex**

```
\chapter{Chapter 1}\label{firstchapter}

Test
```

**Ch01run.tex**

```
\documentclass{book}

\includeonly{Ch01}

\begin{document}

\include{Ch01}
\include{Ch02}

\end{document}
```

The same structure applicable for all chapters, hence group of persons handles each chapters separately. In this, Some times `??` error, happens in some files, but when rerun the particular file solves the issue, but after some time again the same ?? happening to some other chapter. How can I fix this?

I've created a test project (https://www.overleaf.com/project/640708681ddf247f0fe3645a) in `Overleaf`, and now trying with the file `xr.sty`, also followed the steps described in https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Cross_referencing_with_the_xr_package_in_Overleaf but the same error exists, please suggest your valuable suggestions

Comment: You need to compile the full document before excluding other chapters you reference to?

Comment: I don‘t see any \ref statements referring to labels you introduced. Please add so your example works when we copy and compile it. Please recall, referencing is a two step process, requiring two compile runs.

Comment: you always get ?? on the first run, cross references resolve on later runs. normally overleaf (latexmk) runs latex enough times to resolve all references, but if you have an error that means latex can not reach the end it may not be able to write the data to the aux file until the error is fixed. the error may be unrelated to references

Comment: @DavidCarlisle and @MS-SPO; still the same error exists, actually it works but some time comes correctly and some times won't, Kindly confirm that, is there any options available to export/import `\label` values into a TeX file through any `.sty` file support?

Comment: I can not guess what you mean by the last comment sorry. But as you have not shown any example it's really not easy to help. First check if you have any errors, if you have a red error count at the top bar of the overleaf display, fix the  errors before worrying about any output. The output is not intended to be usable after an error, just a debugging aid.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sorry, what my concern is, is there any `.sty` file like `xr.sty`, which helps to import the `\label` values from one chapter to another chapter externally

Comment: there can be no such style as labels are not handled per chapter they are handled at the end of the document (and at the  start when the saved values are read in) I can not see how you can get the behaviour you describe unless you have errors in the document, and no style can automatically fix unknown errors.

Comment: Oh you have `\includeonly{Ch01}`   so you need to make one run of the full document to get all the references, then do `\includeonly{Ch01}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sorry to disturb, I have updated my question with `Overleaf` link and now I'm trying with the file `xr.sty`, please suggest

Comment: xr package is not usable at all with chapters that are used with `\include`. The solution is as I said to do one run without `\includeonly` so all cross references are collected, then add `\includeonly` to restrict to the desired chapter.

Comment: Please don't use external links, your question is archived here forever and will not make sense if you change that overleaf project. Just fix your code fragment in the question  to be a real example.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found solution based on `how to use xr package in overleaf` https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Cross_referencing_with_the_xr_package_in_Overleaf, this helps to solve the issue

Comment: Please include the relevant parts of the solution directly in your answer so it remains helpful for future users in case the link no longer works.

Answer (score 1):

The command `\includeonly`, to work properly, relies on the auxiliary (`.aux`) files of the included chapters. These files are produced when compiling the whole project once, *without* the command `\includeonly`; in Overleaf, you can see these `.aux` files under "Show cached files" ([see here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Clearing_the_cache)). In your case, you should find `Ch01.aux`, `Ch02.aux`. Without these files, `\includeonly` does not work as intended and produces `??` and errors ([see this answer for how to use `\includeonly`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87010/correct-way-to-use-include-and-includeonly-when-writing-a-large-document-like-a/87011#87011)).

What might be happening to you (probably the same that happened to me) is that Overleaf deletes the `.aux` files of the included chapters after some time, so even if you re-compile all the chapters, after some time you still get `??` and a bunch of errors. [To solve this problem it is possible to add a few lines in the preamble, see this other post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/706344/overleaf-seems-to-automatically-delete-aux-files-problem-with-command-include).